# What's the keyboard shortcut to pop out a tab to a separate window?

Tags: sublimetext2

In Sublime Text 2, what's the keyboard shortcut to pop out a tab to a separate window?

Comment: Relatively sure that doesn't exist.

Answer (score -3):

Unfortunately, there isn't one. Your operating system may offer functionality to be able to create it - for example System Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts > Application Shortcuts in MacOSX.